# Get the Job predecessor Job name in a scriopt

Tags: autosys

I have a mail Job (Job-Mail) that run with this condition

> s(Job A)|s(Job B)|s(Job C)

, if any of the three Jobs success than run the mail Job, and it run as I expected.

Now I need to get the name of success predecessor Job that trigger Job-Mail in the script as I have a logic in the script to generate file A incase Job A success and to generate file B incase Job B success

Answer (score 0):

Inside shell scripts, use 
`job_depends -c -j Job-Mail` and look for Atomic conditions. You will get all predecessor jobs and their status. With help of sed/awk/grep, see which jobs are sucesss and return the name. If more than 1 job success then raise exception or see which finished first and return that.

Alternatively, you can do a if else in shell and condition should be something like

```
jobWhichKickedJob-Mail = ""
if `autostatus -j Job A` = 'SUCCESS' then 
  jobWhichKickedJob-Mail = "Job A"
elif `autostatus -j Job B` = 'SUCCESS' then 
  jobWhichKickedJob-Mail = "Job B"
else 
  jobWhichKickedJob-Mail = "Job C"
```

and use this variable.

Note: By the time your script is running, if any other job succeeds, you might not get correct result.

Comment: You will **not** be able to identify the triggered job using this logic, because the Job A, B or C could have been on SUCCESS from the previous days run. You don't have any indication on which job triggered Job-Mail currently